# Angular 8 Can't resolve 'fs' after installing @types/node

Tags: node.js, angular, db2, fs

I have a pretty basic Angular web app right now and I'm trying to connect to Db2 using the **ibm_db** driver. After installing ibm_db, it asked me to install `@types/node` and then add `"types": ["node"]` to my `tsconfig.app.json` in root under `compilerOptions`.

When I add `ibmdb = require("ibm_db");` to my main `component.ts` file, it throws errors in the console about `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'`.

I've tried a few different solutions I found online but none have worked. A lot of people are saying adding

```
"browser": {
   "fs": false,
   "os": false,
   "path": false
}
```

to `package.json` fixes this, and it does resolve my errors but then my webapp is blank when I try to load it.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I'm new to Angular. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use `ibm_db` in a browser?? Because if so then it's not gonna work. Both `ibm_db` and `fs` are serverside only modules. They are not gonna work in a browser.

Comment: @Molda yeah I am, how am I supposed to set it up then on a bluemix website?

Comment: What is Bluemix...? Typically, you have the client (browser-side) and a server component.

Comment: It's hard to tell since i have no idea how Bluemix works. But the basic idea is that you send a request from browser to your server(e.g. GET /api/users) and on the server you connect to db, query the user db and send the data(users) returned from db to browser.

Comment: Bluemix is just a website I'm using that shows the same view as localhost would when I host with Angular. Angular is just made up of html, scss, spec, and ts files so I tried putting the ibm_db code into the ts file with the rest of the computational stuff.

Comment: If I find a way to add JS files to my angular project, would that be able to run ibm_db?